# Python hide float decimals if it's over 13?

Tags: python

i was doing some calculation and i got something like this:

```
newInteger = 200
newFloat = 200.0

if newInteger >= newFloat:
    print "Something"
```

when i run my application it didn't print it out but when i test it on python shell, it print `Something`!!.

so i test this,

```
>>> number = 200.0000000000001
>>> number
200.0000000000001
```

but when decimals goes over 13, like so:

```
>>> number = 200.00000000000001
>>> number
200.0
```

does python hide the decimal numbers but showing as rounded? knowing the result is quite important when debugging.

is there any way that i can get the full decimals? (i did look up at python documentation, it didn't say anything about printing actual float number.)

Comment: It's called floating point round-off error. It has to do with how Python stores floats (in binary), which makes it impossible for floats to have 100% precision.

Comment: More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called floating point round-off error. It has to do with how Python stores floats (in binary), which makes it impossible for floats to have 100% precision.

Here's more info in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

See the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module if you need more precision.

If you just want to quickly compare two numbers, there are a couple of tricks for floating point comparison. One of the most popular is comparing the relative error to the machine precision (epsilon):

```
import sys

def float_equality(x, y, epsilon=sys.float_info.epsilon):
    return abs(x - y) <= epsilon * max(abs(x), abs(y))
```

But this too, is not perfect. For a discussion of the imperfections of this method and some more accurate alternatives, see this [article about comparing floats](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

Comment: i see... but is there any way that i can print it, if i want to see it?

Comment: If I were you, I would use the decimal module that I linked to above.

Answer (score 4):

Python tends to round numbers:

```
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> "{0:.50f}".format(math.pi)
'3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500'
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(math.pi)
'3.14'
```

However, floating point numbers have a specific precision and you can't go beyod it. You can't store arbitrary numbers in floating point:

```
>>> number = 200.00000000000001
>>> "{:.25f}".format(number)
'200.0000000000000000000000000'
```

For integers the floating point limit is 2**53:

```
>>> 2.0**53
9007199254740992.0
>>> 2.0**53 + 1
9007199254740992.0
>>> 2.0**53 + 2
9007199254740994.0
```

If you want to store arbitrary decimal numbers you should use Decimal module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> number = Decimal("200.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001")
>>> number
Decimal('200.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001')
```